# How to calculate the sum of binomials?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I want to prove below:

n is natural number.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{2n}{n+k} =\frac{1}{2}(n+1) \binom{2n}{n+1}$$

Please tell me above proof.

Comment: @takoika I hope I didn't mess up your question.

Comment: Wolframalpha solves (1/2)(n+1)(2n_C_(n+1)).I want to know its process.

Comment: without $k$ this is partial sum of rows of Pascal triangle, which doesn't have a closed-form expression. This one probably doesn't have one either. You can asymptotics though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}=(1+1)^{2n}=4^n
$$
and
$$
\binom{m}{j}=\binom{m}{m-j}
$$
and 
$$
j\binom{m}{j}=m\binom{m-1}{j-1}
$$
to simplify your expression.

---

For instance, combining them to
\begin{align}
2k\binom{2n}{n+k}&=(n+k)\binom{2n}{n+k}-(n-k)\binom{2n}{n-k}\\[1em]
&=2n\binom{2n-1}{n+k-1}-2n\binom{2n-1}{n-k-1}\\[1em]
&=2n\binom{2n-1}{n+k-1}-2n\binom{2n-1}{n+k}
\end{align}
Perhaps this can be used in a telescoping sum.

Comment: Is first fomula wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but yes. Shameful mistake.